# Temporal complexity of a recursive algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, temporal

I just get this algorithm from another post, but I need to know how can I calculate the `temporal complexity` of this algorithm? I am a student and don't know much about how to do it.

```
 public static void getSum(int[] numbersArray, int starting, int sum)
 {
   if(numbersArray.length == starting)
   {
     // Now we print sum here
     System.out.println(sum);
     return;
   }

   int value = sum + numbersArray[starting];

   getSum(numbersArray, starting + 1, value);
   getSum(numbersArray, starting + 1, sum);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `numbersArray` has length 5.  I'm assuming that someone is going to call this with `starting` = 0, i.e. `getSum(numbersArray, 0, 0)`.  Now:

This is going to call `getSum(numbersArray, 1, x)` twice.

Each call of `getSum(numbersArray, 1, x)` will call `getSum(numbersArray, 2, x)` twice.

Each call of `getSum(numbersArray, 2, x)` will call `getSum(numbersArray, 3, x)` twice.  And so on.

When we get to `getSum(numbersArray, 5, x)`, the time is constant; let's call it *baseTime*.

Suppose we say T(n) is the time to execute `getSum(numbersArray, n, x)`.  Then T(5) is *baseTime*; T(4) = 2*T(5); T(3) = 2*T(4); and so on.  This means that the time for the entire call, T(0) = 2*T(1) = 2*2*T(2) = 2*2*2*T(3) = 2*2*2*2*T(4) = 2*2*2*2*2*T(5) = 2*2*2*2*2**baseTime*.  What this tells you is that the time for the algorithm is proportional to 2<sup>m</sup> where *m* is the length of the array.  So the answer would be written as O(2<sup>m</sup>).